# Where is the subject for the verb "has"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> How banks are defined in America has changed over time.

Where is the subject for the verb "has"? How is this type of sentence formed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [*How banks are defined in America*] *has changed over time*.

The bracketed element is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as **subject** of the sentence.

The meaning is:

"The answer to the question 'How are banks defined in America?' has changed over time."

Comment: There is no embedded question. questions follow the format: How are X defined in America?

Comment: @Lambie It's clearly an interrogative, since it has no inversion. What else could it possibly be?

Comment: It just is not a question **form**: How **are banks** defined? **How banks are defined is x" is not a question.

Comment: @Lambie Nonsense. Of course it's an interrogative content clause.

Comment: No, that's nonsense. The sine qua non for an interrogative form with be is the inversion. No inversion, no interrogative form.

Comment: @Lambie Unlike most main clauses, subordinate interrogatives don't have inversion.

Comment: The manner in which banks are defined in America has changed over time. = How banks are defined.

Comment: @Lambie That's wrong. "How" doesn't occur in fused relatives like that. And FYI subordinate interrogatives don't have inversion with any verb, including "be".

Comment: In "How I live my life is nobody's business but my own." is "How I live my life" also a subordinate interrogative?

Comment: The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* gives two examples of "how" in fused relatives, including "We will not change how we use future contracts during the term of this Prospectus", in chapter 12, §6.4, page 1077. (N.B. it describes this as "rare and quite marginal", and marks the example as grammatical in some dialects only.) So although Lambie seems to be trapped in a grade-school understanding of English grammar, I think (s)he might be right that the OP's specific example is a fused relative rather than an interrogative content clause. (I'm not sure, though.)

Answer (score 9):

The subject is "How banks are defined in America".

The sentence is formed in the common sentence order subject-verb-object (or SVO), except that there is no object in this sentence, so it is just subject-verb. A similar but simpler sentence would be something like "He has changed over time."

The verb "change" is in the present perfect tense "has changed", and "over time" is an adverb modifying the verb.

Comment: There is no object in this sentence. Just like there is no object in "You've changed!"

Comment: "changed" is being used as an intransitive verb, so there's no object.

Comment: rather, there is no object, so "change" is being used as an intransitive verb. But the question wasn't whether "change" is being used as an intransitive verb.